# Spring-Boot MapStruct Generic implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, mapper

```
public abstract class ServiceGenericImpl<E extends BaseEntity,T extends BaseDto>
    implements ServiceGeneric<T> {

   @Autowired
   protected GenericRepository<E> genericRepository;


   @Autowired
   protected GenericMapper<E,T> genericMapper;

   // code...
}
```

I try to generate Generic Implementation. Because many mapper such as city,person etc.

there is an error
"Could not autowire. No beans of 'GenericMapper<E, T>' type found." How to generic implementation mapper and repository on service?

```
public interface GenericMapper<E extends BaseEntity, T extends BaseDto> {
   DTO toDTO(E entity);
   E toEntity(T dto);
}

@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface CityMapper extends GenericMapper<City, CityDto> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapstruct needs some concrete classes e.g. X, XDto, so that it can analyse their properties and generate specific mapping code at compile time.